# How to Apply Default Layout to All Error Pages in SvelteKit?

Tags: layout, svelte, sveltekit

I want to have a default layout with a navbar that should be applied to all pages except certain "account" pages (e.g., Sign In, Sign Out, Register).

*Here's what I've done so far:*

1. I created two groups (account) and (main) to separate the layout behaviors.
2. I added the layout and the page file directly into the (main) group so that the main index page (/) will use the layout and pages within this group.

However, I'm facing a challenge with applying this default layout to error pages.

*The Problem:*

If I create a +error.svelte document in the root directory, it doesn't use the layout in the (main) group.
On the other hand, if I place +error.svelte within the (main) group, even errors on the main pages don't get the layout because the error seems to propagate to the parent folder structure(?).

*What I'm Looking For:*

How can I configure SvelteKit so that all error pages, regardless of the group they originate from, use the default layout from the (main) group? (Even errors from the account group have the default layout)

## Current Folder Structure:

```
src/
├── routes/
│   ├── (account)/
│   │   ├── account/
│   │   │   └── +page.svelte
│   │   └── +layout.svelte
│   ├── (main)/
│   │   ├── __layout.svelte (Main layout with navbar)
│   │   ├── index.svelte (Main index page)
│   │   └── ... (Other pages that use the main layout)
```

## Expected Folder Structure:

```
src/
├── routes/
│   ├── (account)/
│   │   └── ... (like above)
│   ├── (main)/
│   │   ├── +layout.svelte (Main layout with navbar)
│   │   ├── +page.svelte
│   │   └── ... (Other pages that use the main layout)
│   └── +error.svelte (Expected to have the layout from the (main) group but doesn't)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a `Navbar`, `Header`, `Footer` component and import to your `+error.svelte` if you want error page have these components.
`+layout.svelte` is only for `+page.layout`.
My simple folder structure is like this:
[Sveltekit simple folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsHRb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Following your expected folder structure, one option is to do the following

**Create a component** defining the layout with necessary named slots, call it, say *src/component/main_layout.svelte*. It's content should be fairly similarly to the current *src/routes/main/+layout.svelte* file.

**Rewrite *src/routes/main/+layout.svelte* using the component**

**Use the same component in *src/routes/+error.svelte*** file as your skeleton and personalize for each error type by using the named slots.

Since both files are reusing the same component, **any update in the *src/component/main_layout.svelte* file should reflected in *src/routes/main/+layout.svelte*, and *src/routes/+error.svelte*.**

Kindly ensure **no other *+error.svelte* file** inside any nested folders as sveltekit will look for the closest error boundary, i.e.tracing its way up the folder tree and use the first *+error.svelte* file it encounters.

May not be the best solution, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create `+error.svelte` in 2 different groups that you have such as (account) and (main).

By that way, the error page will take the same level layout to render.

ie:

```
src/routes/(main)
src/routes/(main)/+layout.svelte
src/routes/(main)/+error.svelte

src/routes/(account)
src/routes/(account)/+layout.svelte
src/routes/(account)/+error.svelte
```

If you place `+error.svelte` at the root level, it will take the root `+layout.svelte` automatically.